# Convert pandas dataframe to a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
apple   banana  carrot  diet coke
1         1       1         0
0         1       0         0
1         0       0         0
1         0       1         1
0         1       1         0
0         1       1         0
```

I would like to convert this to the following:

```
[['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'],
 ['banana'],
 ['apple'],
 ['apple', 'carrot', 'diet coke'],
 ['banana', 'carrot'],
 ['banana', 'carrot']]
```

How can I do it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because life is short, I might do something straightforward like

```
>>> fruit = [df.columns[row.astype(bool)].tolist() for row in df.values]
>>> pprint.pprint(fruit)
[['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'],
 ['banana'],
 ['apple'],
 ['apple', 'carrot', 'diet coke'],
 ['banana', 'carrot'],
 ['banana', 'carrot']]
```

This works because we can use a boolean array (`row.astype(bool)`) to select only the elements of `df.columns` where the row has True.

Comment: Very nice solution! I'm kind of embarrassed of mine now :)

Comment: This is great!!! Thanks for this answer, even though I am not the OP. Can you please explain how exactly the element, in this case 1, is replaced by the column name in the output list? I can't wrap my brain around this one.

Comment: Its a charming solution

Comment: @JoeR ,  in this solution `row` is a numpy array.   When you do `row.astype(bool)` you get something like `array([False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)`.   This array of booleans can be used to selectively index `df.columns`,  which is a `pd.Index` object:  `df.columns==Index(['apple', 'banana', 'carrot', 'dietcoke'], dtype='object')`.

Comment: @PedroMDuarte Thanks for your comment Pedro, I am starting to understand now.

Answer (score 2):

@DSM solution is great, however it's working only when your values `1` or `0`. If you need to compare it with other value you could try that:

```
[df.columns[df.ix[i,:]==1].tolist() for i in range(len(df.index))]

In [156]: [df.columns[df.ix[i,:]==1].tolist() for i in range(len(df.index))]
Out[156]:
[['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'],
 ['banana'],
 ['apple'],
 ['apple', 'carrot', 'dietcoke'],
 ['banana', 'carrot'],
 ['banana', 'carrot']]
```

**EDIT**

Although you could just modify a bit @DSM solution:

```
In [177]: [df.columns[row == 1].tolist() for row in df.values]
Out[177]:
[['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'],
 ['banana'],
 ['apple'],
 ['apple', 'carrot', 'dietcoke'],
 ['banana', 'carrot'],
 ['banana', 'carrot']]
```

Some perfomance tests:

```
In [179]: %timeit [df.columns[row == 1].tolist() for row in df.values]
The slowest run took 4.03 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000 loops, best of 3: 212 us per loop

In [180]: %timeit [df.columns[row.astype(bool)].tolist() for row in df.values]
10000 loops, best of 3: 186 us per loop

In [181]: %timeit [df.columns[df.ix[i,:]==1].tolist() for i in range(len(df.index))]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.4 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [24]: import pandas as pd

In [25]: import io

In [26]: data = """                                          
apple   banana  carrot  dietcoke
1         1       1         0
0         1       0         0
1         0       0         0
1         0       1         1
0         1       1         0
0         1       1         0
"""

In [27]: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delimiter='\s+')

In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
   apple  banana  carrot  dietcoke
0      1       1       1         0
1      0       1       0         0
2      1       0       0         0
3      1       0       1         1
4      0       1       1         0
5      0       1       1         0

In [29]: [[df.columns[i] for i,field in enumerate(record) if field == 1] for j,*record in df.itertuples()]
Out[29]: 
[['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'],
 ['banana'],
 ['apple'],
 ['apple', 'carrot', 'dietcoke'],
 ['banana', 'carrot'],
 ['banana', 'carrot']]
```

The solution, without using list comprehension and extended tuple unpacking is shown below:

```
In [32]: result = []

In [33]: for record in df.itertuples():
   ....:     row = []
   ....:     for i,field in enumerate(record[1:]):
   ....:         if field == 1:
   ....:             row.append(df.columns[i])
   ....:     result.append(row)
   ....: 

In [34]: result
Out[34]: 
[['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'],
 ['banana'],
 ['apple'],
 ['apple', 'carrot', 'dietcoke'],
 ['banana', 'carrot'],
 ['banana', 'carrot']]
```

Comment: File "<ipython-input-6-565d2353b297>", line 1
    [[df.columns[i] for i,field in enumerate(record) if record[i]==1] for j,*record in df.itertuples()]
                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Which version of python are you running?

Comment: Python 2.7   Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: posted.  let me know if the alternative solution works for you

Comment: Hi Pedro, use `pd.read_clipboard()` to copy the dataframe from question its much easier.

Comment: @WoodChopper,  thanks! I did not know about `pd.read_clipboard()`

Answer (score 1):

You could treverse and create as Pedro mentioned or just use `stack()`  and `groupby()` to list,

```
df
Out[14]: 
   apple  banana  carrot  diet_coke
0      1       1       1          0
1      0       1       0          0
2      1       0       0          0
3      1       0       1          1
4      0       1       1          0
5      0       1       1          0

df.stack()
Out[15]: 
0  apple        1
   banana       1
   carrot       1
   diet_coke    0
1  apple        0
   banana       1
   carrot       0
   diet_coke    0
2  apple        1
   banana       0
   carrot       0
   diet_coke    0
3  apple        1
   banana       0
   carrot       1
   diet_coke    1
4  apple        0
   banana       1
   carrot       1
   diet_coke    0
5  apple        0
   banana       1
   carrot       1
   diet_coke    0
dtype: int64



df.stack()[df.stack().values ==1].reset_index()
Out[20]: 
    level_0    level_1  0
0         0      apple  1
1         0     banana  1
2         0     carrot  1
3         1     banana  1
4         2      apple  1
5         3      apple  1
6         3     carrot  1
7         3  diet_coke  1
8         4     banana  1
9         4     carrot  1
10        5     banana  1
11        5     carrot  1


newdf.groupby(['level_0'])['level_1'].apply(list)
Out[27]: 
level_0
0       [apple, banana, carrot]
1                      [banana]
2                       [apple]
3    [apple, carrot, diet_coke]
4              [banana, carrot]
5              [banana, carrot]
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```